# TV show about a group of teenagers who go to competitions that involve them catching creatures with a watch-based thing

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

What's that one show where a group of teenagers have to capture small creatures through a watch and combine them with other smaller creatures to form a giant one-- and they have competitions like that?

I remember the show starting off with this boy in a park/forest thing with his own little creature he thought was a pet, and then the pet hears a noise and chases after it, causing the boy to chase after his pet. Then they see a group of people his age training with similar pets-- I think two or three other boys and one girl (the girl had red/brown hair?) with their mentor training them. There was this one boy who leaves the team because he thinks the protagonist is stealing his spot. The girl's parents are also missing.

They go to competitions that involve them catching different creatures with a watch-based thing, and then they merge the tiny creatures together to make a monster to fight the opposition's team.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated?

Comment: *Yo-Kai Watch*?